# Optimization problem where the function is not explicit presented

Tags: python, optimization

How can I iterate over a certain number of variables (r_kso,r_bxo and r_ko) to arrive at a certain target value (mass_ro)?

In the code the target values are commented and the initial guesses aren't. I tried to use scipy optimize package, but I later discovered that package doesn't work on function that are no explicitly presented.

```
#PACKAGES
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
#OXIDIZER

#TARGET
#mass_ro=0.1729

#VARIABLES
r_kso=1*10**-3      #Target=2.7*10**-3
r_bxo=0.3*10**-3    #Target=0.9*10**-3
r_ko=2*10**-3       #Target=4.5*10**-3
#CONSTANTS 
Xi_yo=0.3
l_bxo=6*r_bxo   
n_o=6 

# phi_i_o
c=2**0.5*r_kso*(r_ko-r_bxo)
f=c/(2*n_o*r_bxo**2)
def phi_i_o(z):
    x=z[0]
    F=np.empty(1)
    F[0]=f*x**1.5+x-1
    return F
phi_i_o=float(fsolve(phi_i_o,1))

# lambda_o
mu_o=7.64*10**-6
delta_p=4.4*10**5
rho_o=1140
uk_o=1.94*10**-6
mu_io=phi_i_o*(phi_i_o/(2-phi_i_o))**0.5
f_kso=np.pi*r_kso**2 
mass_io=mu_io*f_kso*(2*rho_o*delta_p)**0.5
W_o=mass_io / ( n_o * np.pi * r_bxo**2 * rho_o ) 
Re_o=W_o*2*r_bxo*uk_o**-1
lambda_o=0.3164*Re_o**(-0.25)

# A_io
A_io=r_kso*(r_ko-r_bxo) / (n_o*r_bxo**2)

# phi_omega_o
d=2*( ( (r_ko-r_bxo)*(r_ko-r_kso-r_bxo)*lambda_o / 2 ) +n_o*r_bxo**2 )
e=c/d
def phi_omega_o(z):
    x=z[0]
    F=np.empty(1)
    F[0]=e*x**1.5+x-1
    return F
phi_omega_o=float(fsolve(phi_omega_o,1))

# A_omega_o
A_omega_o=((1-phi_omega_o)*2**0.5) / (phi_omega_o**(3/2))

# mass_ro
K_0=A_io/A_omega_o
C_o=r_ko-r_bxo/ r_kso
f=np.pi*r_kso**2*(2*rho_o*delta_p)**0.5
g=(phi_omega_o**-2 + (A_io**2*K_0**2) / (1-phi_omega_o) +Xi_yo*n_o*(A_io/C_o)**2)**0.5
mass_ro=f/g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can formulate a small optimization problem for instance. I minimized the difference of the target and actual mass squared. The design vector consists of your 3 variables. I do not get back your target values for *r_kso* and *r_ko* though (they are circa twice as large).I might be that the function has multiple roots, or some calculation error. But anyways, you can follow the structure of the code below to calculate your values.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, minimize
#OXIDIZER

#TARGET
mass_ro_target=0.1729

#VARIABLES
r_kso0=1e-3      #Target=2.7*10**-3
r_bxo0=0.3e-3    #Target=0.9*10**-3
r_ko0=2e-3       #Target=4.5*10**-3
#CONSTANTS
Xi_yo=0.3
l_bxo=6*r_bxo0
n_o=6
mu_o = 7.64e-6
delta_p = 4.4e5
rho_o = 1140
uk_o = 1.94e-6

def func(u):
    r_kso = u[0]
    r_bxo = u[1]
    r_ko = u[2]
    # phi_i_o
    c=2**0.5*r_kso*(r_ko-r_bxo)
    f=c/(2*n_o*r_bxo**2)

    phi_i_o=float(fsolve(lambda x: f*x**1.5+x-1, 1.0))

    # lambda_o
    mu_io=phi_i_o*(phi_i_o/(2-phi_i_o))**0.5
    f_kso=np.pi*r_kso**2
    mass_io=mu_io*f_kso*(2*rho_o*delta_p)**0.5
    W_o=mass_io / ( n_o * np.pi * r_bxo**2 * rho_o )
    Re_o=W_o*2*r_bxo*uk_o**-1
    lambda_o=0.3164*Re_o**(-0.25)

    # A_io
    A_io=r_kso*(r_ko-r_bxo) / (n_o*r_bxo**2)

    # phi_omega_o
    d=2*( ( (r_ko-r_bxo)*(r_ko-r_kso-r_bxo)*lambda_o / 2 ) +n_o*r_bxo**2 )
    e=c/d

    phi_omega_o=float(fsolve(lambda x: e*x**1.5+x-1,1.0))

    # A_omega_o
    A_omega_o=((1-phi_omega_o)*2**0.5) / (phi_omega_o**1.5)

    # mass_ro
    K_0=A_io/A_omega_o
    C_o=r_ko-r_bxo/ r_kso
    f=np.pi*r_kso**2*(2*rho_o*delta_p)**0.5
    g=(phi_omega_o**-2 + (A_io**2*K_0**2) / (1-phi_omega_o) +Xi_yo*n_o*(A_io/C_o)**2)**0.5
    mass_ro=f/g
    print("mass_ro = {}, u = {}".format(mass_ro, u))
    delta_mass = mass_ro - mass_ro_target
    return delta_mass**2

u0 = np.array([r_kso0, r_bxo0, r_ko0])
result = minimize(func, u0, bounds=list(zip(np.zeros(3), np.ones(3)*0.1)), method="SLSQP", tol=1e-8)


print(result)
```

Output:

```
mass_ro = 0.006630000178427132, u = [0.001  0.0003 0.002 ]
mass_ro = 0.006630000178427132, u = [0.001  0.0003 0.002 ]
mass_ro = 0.006630013618867968, u = [0.00100001 0.0003     0.002     ]
mass_ro = 0.006630996425244659, u = [0.001      0.00030001 0.002     ]
mass_ro = 0.006629942573809063, u = [0.001      0.0003     0.00200001]
mass_ro = 1263.2306213159197, u = [0.1 0.1 0. ]
mass_ro = 14.526255285654823, u = [0.0109  0.01027 0.0018 ]
mass_ro = 0.3234236129151228, u = [0.00199  0.001297 0.00198 ]
mass_ro = 0.3234236129151228, u = [0.00199  0.001297 0.00198 ]
mass_ro = 0.32342785077615827, u = [0.00199001 0.001297   0.00198   ]
mass_ro = 0.32342667485180293, u = [0.00199    0.00129701 0.00198   ]
mass_ro = 0.3234222154656966, u = [0.00199    0.001297   0.00198001]
mass_ro = 5.596981526174572e-21, u = [2.37742551e-13 3.62535319e-02 1.00000000e-01]
mass_ro = 0.09816595236403414, u = [0.0010042  0.01861362 0.05053674]
mass_ro = 0.20487808829740692, u = [0.00147417 0.01035809 0.0273878 ]
mass_ro = 0.20487808829740692, u = [0.00147417 0.01035809 0.0273878 ]
mass_ro = 0.20488212268120398, u = [0.00147419 0.01035809 0.0273878 ]
mass_ro = 0.20487812903633662, u = [0.00147417 0.01035811 0.0273878 ]
mass_ro = 0.20487807869460106, u = [0.00147417 0.01035809 0.02738781]
mass_ro = 3.567889122399408e-21, u = [1.89435490e-13 1.11794252e-02 2.55973585e-02]
mass_ro = 0.12218634828569121, u = [0.00112985 0.01054993 0.02696961]
mass_ro = 0.16976608120441192, u = [0.00133776 0.01043409 0.02722212]
mass_ro = 0.16976608120441192, u = [0.00133776 0.01043409 0.02722212]
mass_ro = 0.16976977604696408, u = [0.00133778 0.01043409 0.02722212]
mass_ro = 0.16976611112814918, u = [0.00133776 0.01043411 0.02722212]
mass_ro = 0.1697660740324985, u = [0.00133776 0.01043409 0.02722213]
mass_ro = 0.17255350181202705, u = [0.00134918 0.0103907  0.02715298]
mass_ro = 0.17255350181202705, u = [0.00134918 0.0103907  0.02715298]
mass_ro = 0.17255722425274816, u = [0.0013492  0.0103907  0.02715298]
mass_ro = 0.17255353277871008, u = [0.00134918 0.01039071 0.02715298]
mass_ro = 0.17255349440507634, u = [0.00134918 0.0103907  0.02715299]
mass_ro = 0.1729021449924446, u = [0.0013506  0.01038593 0.02714579]
mass_ro = 0.1729021449924446, u = [0.0013506  0.01038593 0.02714579]
mass_ro = 0.17290587087760173, u = [0.00135062 0.01038593 0.02714579]
mass_ro = 0.17290217608708258, u = [0.0013506  0.01038595 0.02714579]
mass_ro = 0.17290213755667835, u = [0.0013506  0.01038593 0.02714581]
     fun: 4.600992587426244e-12
     jac: array([ 2.00428751e-03,  9.01690827e-06, -2.13701696e-06])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 36
     nit: 6
    njev: 6
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.0013506 , 0.01038593, 0.02714579])
```